# Firebase cloud function: reading database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am currently using Firebase cloud functions to use with the Api.ai and Google assistant SDK.

What I have done so far is this simple response:

```
  function setMachine (app) {
    let mach_id = app.getArgument(MACHINE_ARGUMENT);
    app.tell('Machine ID is'+mach_id );
```

Great  this is working! Assistant answer me with the correct parameter!

Now I want to reply with the data from my database.

I have try 2 different path:

1) Use the database REST api:

```
let url = 'https://myprojectID.firebaseio.com/machine/'+mach_id+'/value.json'
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
     app.tell('Result: '+xmlHttp.responseText);
```

RESULT:
I get an error 500 at: new XMLHttpRequest

2) Trying to use :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.database().ref('machine/'+mach_id+'/value').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var event = snapshot.val();   
        app.tell('Result: '+event);
   });
```

But this also gives an error 500

Comment: Status code 500 signals an internal server error. Is there any more detailed message showing in the logs?

Comment: No, I had no idea how to access a more detailled log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I found that the syntax was not correct, here is the correct one:

```
    admin.database().ref('/machine/'+mach_id+'/value').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
     var event = snapshot.val();   
        app.tell('Result: '+event);
   });
```